# Bought remote server, installed Linux Desktop but SSH from windows no longer connects

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I bought a server and I connected to it from Windows using SSH and I was following a guide to install Ubuntu Desktop gui, it retrieved all the package files etc, the guide said to reboot and now I cannot make a connection to the server via SSH anymore :-S

Comment: Check network connectivity. Check port 22 of your server with `telnet your_server's_ip 22`.

Comment: Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: connect failed. I rebooted the server from the providers portal already but still no result.

Comment: is there a web shell that you can access from the providers web interface? If not, ask your provider to check, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: You should check network access through `PING`, `TRACERT` etc. If you cannot access port 22 of your server, it may be due to a firewall configuration on the server and/or `sshd` being down.

Comment: or the server could not start at all...

Comment: I'll chime in with the others here - you need to contact your provider, and gain direct access via Web-KVM or similar.

Comment: Ok thanks I asked them to reboot and its fine now.